# Group Views' Output

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal Views for an event calendar.
I simply print the output as a table now:
http://quaaoutlodge.com/myspecial-myevents

Now what I would like to do: I want to have items grouped an ordered by month i.e.
I want to have a group of

`January 2014`
a underneath it 
`Test Event 1` and `My Test Event2` 
and there would be another group for `December` that would contain the `New Year's Eve` event,
ow can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is set the grouping field in the format settings.

[image: Format/Settings]

[image: Grouping]